# Approval of edits

Tags: feature-request

With my reputation on Stack Overflow, I am allowed to make edits to questions and they will become immediately visible. However, sometimes there is a question and someone edited it, I call up the edit and approve it. But then it needs three more approval votes before the edit becomes visible. Seems a contradiction?

Comment: In short: it has turned out that people are less conscientious in reading and reviewing the edits of others than they are in composing their own edits. This exacerbated by the gamification mindset of the site: people will auto-approve dozens of edits, blind, just to earn a badge. And then never review edits again, because they were only ever in it for the badge (which is weird to me). Of course, if you really like an edit and don't trust that two other people will approve it, you can skip the review and make the same edit directly to the post using your account. That robs someone of credit.

Comment: @Dan Bron, thanks for the tip. This often hapens with badly formatted code; making it available quickly is in everyone's best interest. So the procedure would then be: open the edit, copy it to clipboard, cancel, open post, paste.

Comment: Yes, sure, but as I said, then whoever proposed the edit will be robbed of credit. And I'm not sure how merge conflicts work, if he original edit *is* ultimately approved. Or maybe an proposed edit on a post is discarded if that post is changed before the edit is approved?

Comment: @DanBron: The latter. It doesn't count toward edit bans, but is otherwise notionally a rejected edit.

Comment: @Dan you can and should "Improve edit" or "Reject and edit" rather than skipping (which both actually insta-approve/reject the edit unilaterally)

Comment: @Cai That's worth posting as answer, I think.

Comment: @Dan Bron and others: maybe if the edit _only_ (or mostly) concerns white space, i.e. properly indenting and formatting, that then the edit needs a 1-person approval (of a person with sufficient credits)?